# R as.numberic returning wrong number

Tags: r, aggregate, numeric, lowercase

I would like to summarize a dataframe ignoring the case. Because a column of my data frame was read in as a factor I first convert this column into a numeric. Doing this, the numbers somehow get mixed up.

My code:

```
    aggregated = as.data.frame(sapply(data, tolower))
    aggregated
```

returns

```
   hashtags   Freq   Company
#33contest   2   @Company1
#cebu   1   @Company1
#community   1   @Company1
#cost   1   @Company1
#countries   1   @Company1
#drug   1   @Company1
```

when I now convert column three into a numeric the results seem to be messed up

```
    aggregated$Freq <-as.numeric(aggregated$Freq)
    aggregated 

hashtags    Freq    Company
#33contest    9    @Company1
#cebu    1    @Company1
#community    1    @Company1
#cost    1    @Company1
#countries    1    @Company1
#drug    1    @Company1
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.vector(aggregated$Freq))`

Comment: Works perfectly. thx. For my understanding: Why do I need to convert this into a vector first?

Comment: you are getting inappropriate values for Freq because it is belongs to `factor class` and and if you will do `as.numeric` to a `factor` you will get internal codes and not the appropriate value. So you either need to convert the class into `character` or `vector` to get the appropriate values. Also have a look at the link indicated as duplicate question.